# how adding new colum to permission table

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions

i am django new bay, i do a lot search but no result.

i need to add **client_id to django permission model** ( save and retrieve ), so when saving user permission client_id should saved with permission and when using has_perm it should check permission for **current user for current client_id**

adding example :

```
user.user_permissions.add(permiObject, request.session['ClientId'])
```

in template if i check :
`{% if perms.app_name.perm_code %}`
this check should be for current ClientId

**Django Permission model field is :** name, content_type, codename
**i need it like this :** :  name, content_type, codename, **client_id**

Comment: Take a look at `django-object-permissions`: https://pypi.org/project/django-object-permissions/

Comment: Sounds like you are misusing the permissions object. What are you trying to achieve? Connect between user and a client ID? I.E user is client, and can only see information that belongs to him? Or connect multiple clients to user, like user is a manager of several clients and can see only info related to them? Either way, it seems more reasonable to modify the user model, add client ID (or list of client IDs) to it, not the permissions class.
You can see an example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Comment: @YuriNudelman, hi, thank you about concern
i have multi tenant (clients ) system with single database schema, i want to separate between user permission in each teneant (client)

Answer (score 2):

I hate to give such answer, because it is not an answer to you direct question, but it really looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

If I understand you correctly, you want to add permission for each user specific per client ID.

The idea behind the Django permissions is that they are supposed to be created at the time of *migration*, i.e. before your server ever starts to run. Here you add something unnatural, clients are added *at runtime* hence you also need to modify permissions *at runtime*. So it looks like Django permissions is not what you need.

What I would do if I were you is simply add a model for my own permissions and connect it to user via the foreign keys.

For example (pseudo code):

```
class MyPermission(Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user   = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Run the migrations, then to add some user a new permission:

```
 user.mypermission_set.create(name="write", client="123")
```

And to test if user has a permission:

```
 user.mypermission_set.filter(name="write", client="123").exists()
```

So hope this helps, not exactly the way you wanted but gives the same functionality, if I understood you correctly.

PS: Maybe you will have to define a custom user model, not sure if Django will simply accept using `mypermission_set` with the standard user model, didn't test it.